# whats the keyword for travels(taxi cab) to get the results from google services .

Tags: android, google-maps

i am using following url to get the details from google services

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=lattitude,longitude&radius=5000&types=hospital&sensor=false&key=yourapikey

i am getting values for hospital, atm , banks, etc but i am unable to get the values for taxi,(travels
) can any one tel me what is the key word for that  ?

Thanks ,
Rajesh

Comment: A taxi is not a geographical place.

Comment: hi @Marcelo i mean travels shop name. or taxi stand